# How to change arrow position in css?

Tags: css

```css
.content > .line > div {
  --line-width: 2px;
  --x-offset: 8px;
  --x-width: 120px;

  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: var(--line-width);
}
.content > .line > div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: var(--x-offset);
  width: var(--x-width);
  height: 100%;
  border-left: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
  border-bottom: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
}
.content > .line > div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(-1 * var(--line-width) * 1.75);
  left: calc(var(--x-offset) + var(--x-width));
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: calc(var(--line-width) * 2.5) solid transparent;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: calc(var(--line-width) * 5) solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line">
    <div>hh</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to change dotted arrow position in Css like above.

I tried changing the css code, But it is coming like bottom. Using the below css code, How to modify it and get the proper shape of the arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some css adjustments will give you this.

```css
.content>.line>div {
  --line-width: 2px;
  --x-offset: 8px;
  --x-width: 120px;

  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: var(--line-width);
}

.content>.line>div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: var(--x-offset);
  width: var(--x-width);
  height: 100%;
  border-right: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
  border-bottom: var(--line-width) dashed currentColor;
}

.content>.line>div:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--line-width) * 1.75);
  left: calc(var(--x-offset) / 2 + var(--x-width));
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: calc(var(--line-width) * 2.5) solid transparent;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: calc(var(--line-width) * 5) solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="line">
    <div>Sample Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i add content on the arrow.? Like in image, Which i updated now.

Comment: @Sundar yes. You just need to adjust the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elementy styles. Just play around those values, it will give you the result